# Load Json (or csv or any other flat file) in Excel JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, json, excel, exceljs

I am trying to create a **JS Add in for Excel** that would load a local JSON file in Excel. I checked the MS documentation but could not find anything. I googled it but found solutions via Node.JS and it seems not to work within the Excel API.

I managed to to load the data in a browser but can not replicate the same in Excel.

If I hardcode the JSON in the code, I am able to retrieve the data.

The following works:

```
const JsonCode = 
{"employees":[
  { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  { "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  { "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }
]}

function readJson() {
  Excel.run(function (context) {
    //var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("C2");
    
    var output = JsonCode.employees[2].lastName
    range.values = output
    //range.format.autofitColumns();

    return context.sync();
})
  .catch(console.log("Error: "))
}
```

But if the file is external, I can not manage to read it in JS.

I tried with:

```
    fetch('Test.JSON')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
```

and

```
function getJson2(){
  Excel.run(function (context) {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("C3");
    const reader = new FileReader();
    var mydata = reader.readAsText(document.getElementById('get_the_file'))
    var mydataparsed = JSON.parse(mydata)
    var output = mydataparsed.employees[2].lastName
    range.values = output
```

But I get either "fetch" not defined or "FileReader is not defined".

Is there any way to read a JSON file in a JS Variable **within the Excel JavaScript API**?

Thanks for any help!!